# Deleting a Attribute With Ganon or any other library php

Tags: php, html-parsing, ganon

I am trying to modify DOM with [Ganon](https://code.google.com/p/ganon/).

My Code:

```
<?php

include 'ganon.php';

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_dom('index.html');
echo $html('tr',2)->getPlainText();
```

I am trying to find the second row in HTML table and then delete it. My question is how can do this with Ganon?

My rough own tries so far which didn't work:

```
$html('tr',2)->getPlainText()->deleteAttribute('tr');
```

Comment: I doubt that deleting an attribute will remove a tag and that any of those does even work on plain text. However, on Stackoverflow we do not give library recommendations any longer. How you can use Ganon should be outlined in Ganon's documentation.

Comment: Ganon supports CSS3 selectors: https://code.google.com/p/ganon/wiki/Selectors - I would use those to find the element you want to manipulate. To delete a tag, you might want to use the detach method: `$node->detach();` More: https://code.google.com/p/ganon/wiki/ModifyElements